# When does $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A^t)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix then its column space is orthogonal to its left null space i.e. $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A^t)^\perp$.

Now suppose $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and let $\lambda_i$ be the corresponding eigenvalues. Suppose $\lambda_m=0$ and $\langle e_m\rangle=\operatorname{Ker}(A-\lambda_mI)=\operatorname{Ker}(A)$. Let $b\in \operatorname{Im}(A)$. Then $b=Ax$ for some $x=\sum x_ie_i$. If $b=\sum b_ie_i$ then we have $\lambda_ix_i=b_i$. So that $b_m=0$. But that would mean $\langle b,e_m\rangle=0$ or $b\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)^\perp$. Then $\operatorname{Im}(A)\subset \operatorname{Ker}(A)^\perp$. And since they share the same dimension, $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A)^\perp$. But then $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A^t)$.

In general, when does this hold? Interestingly enough, if $A$ is symmetric i.e. $A=A^t$, then the eigenvectors of $A$ are orthogonal; the condition that I assumed above.

Comment: Having an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors is a pretty strong condition.

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked for a more general setting where this is true.

Comment: You might want to require that the kernels be nontrivial, as otherwise this holds for any nonsingular square matrix.

Comment: And $\lambda_m=0$ assures me that

Comment: Is $A$ square or not?

Comment: @user7440 The first result is true for non-square matrices as well and I thought of mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

With the SVD of $A$, we have the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra). If we assume the equality to be true, the dimensions for each subspace indicate that $m = n$, i.e. $A$ is square. $A$ does not have to be symmetric though, as the first $r$ columns of $U$ and $V$ can still differ.